# Freezing sandwiches for toasting at work

Tags: freezing, reheating, sandwich, filling

There's a sandwich press at my work and I'm trying to think of a way I can meal prep sandwiches for the whole week in one go. I'm thinking freezing them is the best bet, but I want them to be healthy as well and I'm not sure how vegetables will go in the freezer (probably badly).

Ideally I'll make all the sandwiches on Sunday, then put them in the freezer (wrapped in baking paper). Then, I'll take them to work in the morning (straight from the freezer), put them in the fridge when I get to work, and then put them straight in the sandwich press (inside the baking paper). That way I don't have to clean the press.

What would be the best way to incorporate vegetables into the sandwiches (maybe after toasting them)?

Comment: Hi mint, welcome to Seasoned Advice. We don't take questions with suggestions on which ingredient to use, so I had to edit that part out. The question as a whole is interesting, thanks for posting it!

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/114196/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/36496/67 .  As you're going to lose some of the crispness of the vegetables from freezing & thawing, you might want to try vegetables that have already had the cell walls damaged ... like pickled vegetables or roasted peppers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freezing them will cause the cells to break down slightly, leading to a mushier vegetable. However, since you're planning on heating them anyway, I wouldn't worry about that. Heating will also make the vegetables softer and mushier, so I doubt that the initial freezing will significantly change the quality of the final hot sandwich. I would personally attempt to cook them straight from frozen if you have a freezer at work. The vegetables can release liquid over a slow defrost in the fridge which may affect the structural integrity of the bread.

Comment: If there's a microwave as well, a quick defrost might help, warming the filling too. The press I used to have wouldn't shut on a frozen sandwich and I'd expect the outside to be burnt before the inside was hot.

Answer (score 0):

Tuna fish sandwiches typically freeze well, so I recommend those.

Here is a recipe for that specializes in making the tuna fish sandwich freezer safe: [Freeze Ahead Tuna Sandwiches](https://www.thespruceeats.com/freeze-ahead-tuna-sandwiches-479760)

[image]

Its ingredients are:

- 3 ounces cream cheese, softened
- 2 tablespoons whipped salad dressing (Miracle Whip)
- 1 (6-ounce) can chunk tuna, drained
- 1/4 cup shallot, chopped
- 1/4 cup carrot, shredded
- 1 tablespoon lemon juice
- 2 tablespoons butter, softened
- 8 slices bread (whole wheat, or large sandwich buns)

Though in my opinion, any tuna fish sandwich recipe would work just fine.